# How to load images from a bundle in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can load the image names but not the actual images. The images are stored as pdf so I can scale them.

the code I am using to read the image names is the following

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("FlatIcon.bundle")

do {
    let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey, URLResourceKey.pathKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    return contents.map { $0.lastPathComponent }
}
catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

the code I am using to load the images

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FlatIcon", ofType: "bundle")!
let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
let resourcePath = (bundle?.path(forResource: name
return UIImage(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)
```

The bundle

[image]

**The problem**

No matter what I try I can't use the images inside the bundle

**Update**

Using

```
bundle?.path(forResource: "flat.address.book", ofType: "pdf")
```

it finds the path but when trying to load the UIImage

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)
```

the image will be nil

The problem only happens on pdf files, when using pngs the images load with out a problem

Comment: `name.components(separatedBy: ".").first` is always `flat` which doesn't match any file name. Or it's `address` or `group` and `flat` is missing.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a last change error I made as I was trying different things. Even with the correct name the images will not load, the image is nil. It finds the resourcePath but the Image will not load using UIImage(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the bundle. The problem is merely that a PDF is not an image. It is a PDF. `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` wouldn't work even if the PDF file were in your normal app bundle.

Comment: Yes I just understood that. I though it would work as well because of the way assets folder handles pdfs. I will ask another question regarding that. I need the icons to scale properly....

Comment: By the way, if these _were_ images, what you're doing would _still_ be wrong. You would simply call `UIImage(named:in:compatibleWith:)`, specifying the bundle.

Comment: The reason this works differently from an asset catalog is that what's in the asset catalog is not merely the image / pdf. The asset catalog compiles the data into a special form and processes it. Basically, it is fetching the renderable vector information for you (same now with SVG). There is no API for doing that. So just put your PDFs into an asset catalog and all will be well.

Comment: I was just reading that. The problem is that I want to iterate though images in specific folder. I want to have multiple icon packs and be able to load them separately by folder. I  don't think that's possible to iterate assets in asset catalogue. Maybe if I rename everything like this (flat.1 , flat.2 etc..) but I don't really like that idea

Comment: You're correct. You can use the File Manager to ask "what files are in this folder" but you cannot do that in an asset catalog — you have to know in advance.